# How to get 100 samples each of length 1000 of sample proportion of 5-mers that are AATAA

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am very new to R. Could you please help?

I need to calculate the mean of the sample proportions of 5-mers that are AATAA. But stuck in obtaining 100 samples each of length 1000 of sample proportion of 5-mers that are AATAA from the first 100,000 nucleotides of NC_006620.3

```
install.packages("ape")
library(ape)
library(Biostrings)
dog_ch38 <- read.GenBank("NC_006620.3", as.character = TRUE)
dog_ch38 <- dog_ch38$NC_006620.3[1:100000]
txt <- paste(dog_ch38, collapse = "")
dog_ch38 <- str_to_upper(txt)
dog_ch38
get_DNA_sample <- function(DNA, n){
       N <- str_length(DNA)
       start <- sample(1:(N - n + 1), size = 1)
       return(str_sub(DNA, start, start + n - 1))
   }
get_DNA_sample(dog_ch38, 1000)
```

Comment: are you able to give an example of what you are expecting. Your question is not very clear

Comment: the value of AATAA of 100000 length sample is 176 

s <- DNAString(dog_ch38)

km <- oligonucleotideFrequency(s[1:10^5], 5)
km["AATAA"]
> AATAA 
>   176 

I need 100 samples of length of 1000 sample proportion of 5-mers that are AATAA to calculate mean and sd

Comment: please add it to your question. In your current code, there's no search for AATAA